# run spark with oozie error

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, oozie

i have a simple spark job (spark 1.3) i want to launch it using oozie;
i create two files job.propreties and workflow.xml as follow:

This is my job.propreties

```
nameNode=hdfs://dvs1vm75:8020
jobTracker=dvs1vm75:8032
queueName=default
oozieRoot=oozie
oozie.system.libpath=true
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/admin/zied/spark/workflow.xml
```

and my workflow.xml

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1" name="sample-wf" >
    <start to="myfirstsparkjob"/>
    <action name="myfirstsparkjob">
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <prepare>
                <delete path="${nameNode}/admin/zied/DATA/MSC_output/"/>
            </prepare>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.compress.map.output</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <master>local[*]</master>
            <mode>client</mode>
            <name>Spark Example</name>
            <class>hermi.hermi</class>
            <jar>/lib/z10.jar</jar>

        </spark>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="fail"/>
    </action>

    <kill name="fail">
        <message>spak failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

after running my workflow i got this error on my log [image: error on my log]
how i can fix this error ?

[image: my log job]
Thank you

Comment: Are you sure thats the only message? Its clearly a warning not an error

Comment: i update my question you can see all my log file; Thank you

Comment: i don't see any error in screenshot, add the job logs.

Comment: i update my question with my job log